# Is there a way to automate changing the unresolved name in Maya's reference editor?

Tags: python, maya

I'm not sure if this is a kind of beginner question or not, but I've been searching on internet and nothing seemed to solve my problem.

I'm working in a project that requires to change the `unresolved name` of a referenced object in scene into a form of relative name. Say if I have a sphere in the same folder that my scene's in, and I referenced the sphere into the scene then when I open my reference editor, the 'unresolved name' of the sphere maybe something like `path\to\the\sphere`. I need to change it to `sphere` only, for now I'm doing it manually. Is there a way to automate this process by Python?

I used to dealt with editing texture's path before but it's pretty easy since I can use the `fileTextureName` attribute to change the path and set the path directly. It will be great if reference nodes have some attribute like this

I expect the result of the `unresolved name` will be from something like `path\to\the\ref` to `ref` only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a method I made a while back to repath ABC files that travel with our shots to relative paths, so they will resolve even when pushed to an internal asset server.

Your question is a bit vague, but if you look through the method below and ignore whatever checks you don't want, and obviously re-write to deal with `.mb` or whatever you're using, I think you can make it do what you need.

Please ignore modules in use that you don't need, like `consoleLog` and `config`.

```py
def repathAlembicsRelative():
    '''Repath all alembics in scene, residing in subfolder MISC, to a relative path'''

    out = classes.output()
    out.warnings = []

    consoleLog('Repathing Alembic caches (sims, etc. Not assets)...')

    localFile = cmds.file(query=True, l=True)[0]
    localFolder = os.path.dirname(localFile).replace('\\', '/')

    for obj in cmds.ls(type='reference'):
        try:
            filename = cmds.referenceQuery(obj, filename=True, withoutCopyNumber=True)
            filename = filename.replace('\\', '/').replace('//', '/')
            base = os.path.basename(filename)
            dir = os.path.dirname(filename)

            # Ref is NOT alembic
            if not filename.lower().endswith(config.EXTENSIONS[config.KEY_ALEMBIC]):
                consoleLog('Reference {} is NOT an alembic file. Skipping'.format(obj))
                continue

            # Ref is already on ASSETDIR
            if filename.startswith(config.ASSETDIR):
                consoleLog('Reference {} resides on ASSETDIR ({}). Skipping'.format(obj, config.ASSETDIR))
                continue

            # Ref is NOT in subfolder MISC
            miscPath = '{}/{}'.format(localFolder, config.KEY_MISC)
            miscPathFull = '{}/{}'.format(miscPath, base)
            if not filename == miscPathFull:
                consoleLog('Reference {} is local, but NOT in the MISC folder. Collecting file before repathing'.format(obj))

                try:
                    if not os.path.isdir(miscPath):
                        os.makedirs(miscPath)

                    shutil.copy(filename, miscPathFull)
                    consoleLog('Copied file {} to {}'.format(filename, miscPathFull))
                except Exception as ex:
                    warning = 'Unable to collect file {}: {}'.format(filename, ex)
                    consoleLog(warning)
                    out.warnings.append(warning)
                    continue

            # Failsafe
            if not os.path.isfile(miscPathFull):
                warning = 'File {} passed all checks, but somehow the file does not exist. This is not good.'.format(miscPathFull)
                consoleLog(warning)
                out.warnings.append(warning)
                continue

            # Skip repath if the UNRESOLVED path is already the same as what we're intending to set it to
            relPath = '{}/{}'.format(config.KEY_MISC, base)
            try:
                unresolved = cmds.referenceQuery(obj, filename=True, unresolvedName=True)
                if unresolved == relPath:
                    consoleLog('Unresolved filename for {} ({}) is already correct. Skipping'.format(obj, unresolved))
                    continue
            except Exception as ex:
                consoleLog('Unable to read unresolved filename for {}. Proceeding with pathmapping'.format(obj))

            # Passed all checks, repath to relative
            consoleLog('Repathing {} to {}'.format(filename, relPath))
            cmds.file(relPath, loadReference=obj, type='Alembic', options='v=0')

        except Exception as e:
            consoleLog('Unable to process reference node {}: {}'.format(obj, e))
            continue

    out.success = True # This method is always successful, but may produce warnings
    consoleLog('Done!')
    return out
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much @itypewithmyhands!!! I didnt know that we can use the maya file command to load (or reload) the reference directly from a relative path. So I came up with a simple solution (all the exception I caught earlier on the code above this)

```
for i in sel:
    charRefPath = cmds.referenceQuery(i, filename = 1)

    #REPATH UNRESOLVED REFERENCE NAME WITH RELATIVE NAME
    refNode = cmds.referenceQuery(i, referenceNode = True)
    relPath = charRefPath.split('/')[-1]
    cmds.file(relPath, loadReference = refNode)
```

Comment: Wonderful, I'm happy to hear you got something working! As for your `charRefPath` query, it may be useful for you to include the `withoutCopyNumber` flag if you have multiple references to the same file. This is to avoid getting filenames like `yourFile.mb{1}` etc

Comment: Thanks @itypewithmyhands!! By the way can you tell me what does `options='v=0'` in your line `cmds.file(relPath, loadReference=obj, type='Alembic', options='v=0')` do? I saw it in Mel as well but I'm not quite sure what it does. Thanks!!!

Comment: I can't remember how critical that particular flag is in this context, to be honest. You can read more about it here: http://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2018/ENU/Maya-Tech-Docs/CommandsPython/file.html#flagoptions